# how to place userform basing on a position of a shape

Tags: vba, ms-office, vsto, powerpoint

I am developing add-in to PowerPoint. I want to place created userform on a screen basing on a position of some PowerPoint shape, userform should be placed bit above shape. I managed to find potentially useful methods for Excel: application.usedwidth application.usedheight, activewindow.usedheight and activewindow.usedwidth, but I could not find such methods for PowerPoint.
Is there any way to "convert" PowerPoint shape position into userform position? Is it possible to check widths and heights of all used taskpanes to determine position of "pane" with slide etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I managed to do it.

```
private void UpdatePosition(PPT.Shape shape, PPT.Presentation pres)
{
this.Left = pres.Application.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsX((float)(0 + shape.left + 0.5 * shape.Width)) - (0.5 * this.Width);
this.Top = pres.Application.ActiveWindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY((float)(0 + shape.Top - 20)) - this.Height;
}
```